# Multidimensional series: an application of quantum field theory

Tags: nt.number-theory, sequences-and-series, quantum-field-theory, eisenstein-series

While computing the quantum vacuum energy of a real scalar field defined on $\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{T}^3$, I encountered the following sum:

$$ \sum_{n_1^2+n_2^2+n_3^2\geq 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(n_1^2+n_2^2+n_3^2)^2} $$

Does it have a known exact result?

Thank you.

EDIT: What is the value of Epstein $\zeta_3(2)$? Where the Epstein zeta function is defined as
$$\zeta_k(s)=\sum_{\mathbb{Z}^k/\{0\}} \frac{1}{(n_1^2+....n_k^2)^s}$$

Comment: Maybe you can get relevant information typing "multiple zeta values" in a search engine.

Comment: According to Legendre's theorem, all numbers not of the form $4^a(8k-1), k=1,2,...$ can be written as sum of three squares. So, this is $$\zeta(2)-\sum_{a=0}^{\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{16^a(8k-1)^2}=\zeta(2)-\frac{16}{15}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(8k-1)^2}\right)$$.

Comment: @AlapanDas : I don't think this will work, because the representation as the sum of three squares is not unique in general, even if $n_1,n_2,n_3$ are assumed to be natural numbers -- see e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2068160/determining-the-number-of-ways-a-number-can-be-written-as-sum-of-three-squares

Comment: @Losif Pinelis Yes. As nothing was mentioned clearly about $n_1,n_2,n_3$  I just assumed it as the sum of all squares of inverses of all those number which are sum of three squares.

Comment: What do you mean by $\sum\limits_{n_1^2+n_2^2+n_3^2\ge1}^\infty$?

Comment: @IosifPinelis I think they mean $\sum^\infty_{(n_1,n_2,n_3)\in\{(n_1,n_2,n_3)\in\mathbb{R}^3:n_1^2+n_2^2+n_3^2\geq1\}}$.

Comment: I mean that $n_{1,2,3}$ can take any integer value, except clearly $n_1=n_2=n_3=0$.

Comment: Possibly related question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/228760/is-special-value-of-epstein-zeta-function-in-3-variables-a-period